# How to start a 3rdparty systemd service from a debian package

Tags: debian, systemd, services, packaging

I have a debian package which contains configuration for `systemd-networkd` e.g. I configure my interface IP.

That only makes sense if `systemd-networkd` is running.

Because of that I want to ensure that the service is enabled and running.
But putting this in postinst feels wrong:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
systemctl start systemd-networkd
```

What is the proper way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is normally nothing wrong with using `systemctl enable` in `postinst` on services deployed by your package.  Many Debian packages use `deb-systemd-helper` instead which takes care of a few details (like respecting vendor preset and explicitly disabled or masked service).

`systemd-networkd.service` is deployed by `systemd` itself.  If we inspect `systemd.postinst`, we already see that `systemd` uses `systemctl` to manage this unit.

```
$ dpkg -S /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service
systemd: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service

$ grep systemd-networkd.service -C3 /var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.postinst
if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    _systemctl daemon-reexec || true
    ...
    _systemctl try-restart systemd-networkd.service || true
    _systemctl try-restart systemd-journald.service || true
fi
```

**However, it is unusual to enable a service owned by another package.**  Instead, consider using unit relationships instead.

If your package deploys its own systemd unit which depends on this network configuration, then it's a simple matter of adding the following to your `[Unit]` section:

```
[Unit]
Requires=systemd-networkd.service
After=systemd-networkd.service
```

This will ensure that `systemd-networkd.service` is started when your unit starts, and your unit will not start if `systemd-networkd.service` fails to start.

If you don't have any units in your package, then consider simply creating a target to do this for you:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/mypackage.target
[Unit]
Description=MyPackage unit dependency management
Requires=systemd-networkd.service
After=systemd-networkd.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then manage it in your maintainer scripts:

```
# postinst
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
        deb-systemd-helper unmask 'mypackage.target' >/dev/null || true

        if deb-systemd-helper --quiet was-enabled 'mypackage.target'; then
                deb-systemd-helper enable 'mypackage.target' >/dev/null || true
        else
                deb-systemd-helper update-state 'mypackage.target' >/dev/null || true
        fi
fi
```

```
# prerm
if [ "$1" = remove ] ; then
        deb-systemd-invoke stop 'mypackage.target' >/dev/null || true
fi
```

```
# postrm
if [ "$1" = remove ] ; then
        systemctl --system daemon-reload >/dev/null || true
fi
if [ "$1" = "purge" ]; then
        deb-systemd-helper purge 'mypackage.target' >/dev/null || true
fi
```

If you are using `debian/rules` and debhelper to create your packages, then consider using [`dh_installsystemd`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/debhelper/dh_installsystemd.1.en.html) which will add this to your maintainer scripts automatically in the `@DEBHELPER@` placeholder.